# Indoor mapping tool with API

Tags: library, programming, maps

I need to develop a small application that shows an indoor map. It will be developed in C#, the platform is not decided yet (but it is Windows. Probably either WPF or ASP.MVC, but I'm also thinking of an option of html+javascript that connect over rest to the data provider written in C# - if I have to use google maps or something alike)

Are there any software/libraries I could reuse for this task? The map should look like an indoor office + layer of labeled points. Layer of labeled points will be provided by already existing code. Possibly capable of working offline.

It can be either a separate tool with API/plugin support or library I could embed in my application.

For now there are no other requirements.

P.S. I already have an existing application that will be a data provider and it is written in WPF.

Comment: Show a map: `picturebox.Image=Image.FromFile("floor.png");`? Works on Windows, is compatible with C#. Depending on the image content it looks like an indoor map, you just need to draw the image in the way you want. What I want to say: your requirements are incomplete.

Comment: @ThomasWeller This was my approach as well, but customer wants some tool to be used to be able to accommodate requirements he cannot name, but knows for sure any tool will fulfill :)

Comment: @ThomasWeller I don't see much sense in using any tool. Maybe some control, but given current requirements, simple picturebox should work great. But I need to come up with estimation for different options, including using a separate tool - so this how I ended up asking this question